# A website that provides API for multi currencies

Tags: api, ethereum, monero

Can you please help me to find a wallet that provides API for multiple currencies such as: BTC, ETH, XMR, BCH, LTC, DASH.

I want to create new address for each of the currencies and check if there is a payment on the address.

Thank you